# How to drive two 3v relays safely from Raspberry PI?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, relay

I use PI 4 to power two 3v relays. One is controlling 5v dc, another 12v dc. And about once a minute I am switching each relay signal state to On/Off
So each relay is connected to 3v pin, ground pin and signal GPIO on the PI.
Do I need to put some protection, like resistors, diodes on the board? What exactly? Or is this setup safe? I tried to google the answer but did not find any information on pi+3v relays
My relays are [these ones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZM84BVX)

Here is my board attached.
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The only thing I can add to the answers you have is this: `In general, you should avoid buying electronic components from vendors who do not provide a spec sheet`. The information provided on the Amazon seller's page is incomplete and unreliable. When driving ***anything*** directly from a GPIO pin, you should know how much current is required. This due to the fact that the GPIO gates are rather *wimpy*, and poorly documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relay modules contain all the protection needed for the Pi.  There is no need to do anything else to protect the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

No one can say because the linked page has **ABSOLUTELY NO specifications**.

Caveat emptor!

Using a relay AND an opto-isolator is NONSENSE and indicates whoever "designed" the module has little experience or understanding of circuit design. The opto-isolator just adds inefficiency.

Comment: Though isolation is not required, why not use an opto instead of a transistor? The difference in efficiency is negligible as the relay coil is the major factor. Those few mA required by the opto are much less than the coil current.

Comment: @SimSon you need ~15mA to drive an opto-isolator, which is close to the GPIO per pin max and uses a significant part of the 50mA total available AND you need a transistor to drive the relay.